# Curve fitting Implicit functions in MATLAB using cftool

Tags: matlab, implicit, curve-fitting

I have a set of data (I,V) values(a list of > 100 values) which i can upload onto matlab.

What I need is a method to extract parameters from the equation:

```
I = Iph - Io*(exp((V+I*Rs)/n*Vt)-1) - ((V+I*Rs)/Rsh)
```

Which is a simple equation for a single diode model of a solar cell.

The following are the parameters which I should be able to obtain after curve fitting. I hope someone can help me on this.

- Io
- Iph
- Rs
- Rsh
- n
- Vt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `cftool`, then from the main `Curve Fitting Tool` window, select `Tools>Custom Equation`, then select the `General Equations` tab. You should be able to straightforwardly enter the equation you mention here. If you want, and you have suitable values available, you can also set some initial guesses for the parameters, and lower and upper bounds - this is likely to help with the fitting process.

Once you've done that, you can import your dataset of (I, V) values into `cftool` using the `Data` button. Finally click the `Fitting` button, select your data and custom equation, and click `Fit`. You should get a nice fitted curve, and some fitted parameters that you can export to MATLAB.

Comment: I've done that before. Just in case for notice: its an implicit function and it gives an error if put in that order. Clarifying with the equation:     I = Iph - Io*(exp((V+I*Rs)/n*Vt)-1) - ((V+I*Rs)/Rsh)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - in that case, the method I suggested won't work. I don't think it's going to be easy to do this directly with cftool - I would suggest rearranging the equation until it's not implicit. Sorry I can't be of more help.